# Issue with Delete Action returning HttpNotFound MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i have list of user Emails and than i try to make delete method , but i didnt understand why it just returning HttpNotFound , did i miss something!Can anyone direct me in the right direction? thx

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Delete(string User) 
{

    var db = new DataContext();
    var u = db.PX.Find(User);
    if (u==null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(u);

}
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(string User)
{
    var db = new DataContext();
    var u = db.PX.Find(User);
    db.PX.Remove(u);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

View - Index:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var user in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>

                     <a href="/User/Delete?User=@user.Email">delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Class :

```
public class user
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    private string password = "";

    } }
}
```

Comment: `id` != `User`. Parameter names must match route values. I also highly doubt that `user.Email` is an int.

Comment: @CodeCaster  sorry i didnt understand wat you saying id!=User!! , if its possible would you give me an ex with my code :-) and Email is an string , i just update my question

Comment: The second sentence of my comment explains that. You're passing `id` in the query string, but your action method's parameter name is `User`. They must match.

Comment: @CodeCaster Ahhhh sorryy , u right :)

Comment: @CodeCaster , i just edit that ,but i got this Cant found Delete view , and its right , but i want delete mails in same page my index you know , click on delete show me a msg or just deleted , how can i do that ?! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider updating your controller to the following, which simplifies the query to the PX table and ensures that you grab the appropriate value:

```
public ActionResult Delete(string User) 
{

    var db = new DataContext();
    var u = db.PX.Where(x=> x.Email == User).FirstOrDefault();  //This line updated
    db.PX.Remove(u);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");

}
```

---

EDIT to reflect comment

In your Delete(string User) method, you are trying to return the Delete view, but really you want to reroute to the Index view.

Comment: I just changed it , but i get this : The view 'Delete' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. but idont wanna view for delete , i just wanna delete in the same page in my index, when i click on delete its just deleted or show msg , or use delete action with out view

Comment: @ManDown Try adjusting your controller to reflect the updated code

Answer (score 0):

`DbSet.Find` takes the primary key of the entity (usually a `long` or `Guid`). If no entity with this primary key is found, it returns null.

If the user email is not the primary key in the DB, look up the user with `SingleOrDefault` instead. `SingleOrDefault` will throw an exception if more than one record matches the given criteria (we want this because the Email is used to identify users uniquely). If no matching record is found, it returns null.

```
var u = db.PX.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Email == User);
```

Comment: tnx Georg, i changed it but i get this The view 'Delete' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. but i dont wanna view for view , i want when i click on the delete button ,its just deleted in same page or show msg after deleted

Comment: Then you probably want to `return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK); ` instead of `return View()`. To stay on the same page and show a message, submit the delete request with jQuery ajax and insert the success message into the DOM in the `success` callback.

Comment: Alright Georg , i will try dat to , tnx for your help :-)